# Syntax of ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I am assigning `ng-class` to an element using this.

```
ng-class="{'level-' + {{row.level}}:true,active:TestFlag==true}"
```

but it is giving me tons of errors. What is wrong with its syntax? What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: maybe ng-class="{'level-' + row.level:true,active:TestFlag==true}"

Comment: @doodeec error, + unexpected

Comment: what is active and test flag could you please show complete code or set up a plunker please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

`ng-class="{'level-{{row.level}}': true, active: TestFlag==true}"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to pull the first part off and do it like this:

```
ng-class="{active:TestFlag}" class="{{'level-' + row.level}}"
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/NSZbm1sntT3uwDgx4g0L?p=preview

You can also build an object in your controller:

```
$scope.classSet = {};
$scope.classSet['level-' + $scope.row.level] = true;
$scope.classSet['active'] = $scope.TestFlag;

 <p ng-class="classSet">Here</p>
```

Comment: thanks, your method is working, but is there any way to do this only using `ng-class`